# How to link two xibs?

Tags: cell, tableview, nib

I've to custom cells each in an seperatea .xib file (and for each of them a seperate .h and .m file)

I need these two custom cells in my tableview (Controller). Thats an seperate file, too.

How is it posible to link the two custom cells to the tableviewController?

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in the data source of the tableview (in many cases the tableview controller instance), load the approprate nib file.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your fast reply. 
mhh, i am really new to that so could you please tell me how to link multiple files? The apple sample code isn't that helpfull. They store all customcells in one controller.